# ggplot2 is skipping a time interval on the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R 3.2.3 through RStudio Version 0.99.491, on Windows 10 64bit...Making my first geom_line ggplot chart I thought I successfully navigagted the problem with the brute force of a newbie. Until, with help, I figured out the POSIXct problem, showing that the graph ticks skip the 02:00 PM interval on the x-axis, going straight to 03:00 PM interval, but with the 02:00 PM data. 
Here is the [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1clmu3pfGAJcflQWa1xyxfJpZJyDK23nKa0odiA61vxw/edit?usp=sharing) to start the first transformation.

Here is the [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBwTb.jpg)

```
  library(reshape2)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(scales)

myData_on <- melt(line_hour_on, id.vars = "time")  
dat_on <- myData_on[myData_on$time != "Total",]
dat_on$time_ <- as.POSIXct(paste(dat_on$time),origin = "7:00 AM", format = "%H")

      on_nov <- dat_on[dat_on$variable=="nov",]
      ggplot(data=dat_on, aes(x=time_, y=value, group =variable, colour = variable)) +

                geom_line(data = dat_on, size = 2, alpha = 0.75) +
                geom_point(data = dat_on, size =3, alpha = 0.75) +

                geom_line(data = on_nov, color = "black", size = 3, alpha = 0.60) +
                geom_point(data = on_nov, color = "grey30", size = 6.5) +
                geom_line(data = on_nov, color = "white", size = 1.5, alpha = 0.97) +
                geom_point(data = on_nov, color = "white", size = 5, alpha = 0.97) +
                geom_point(data = on_nov, color = "blue", size = 3, alpha = 0.25) +

                scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%I:%M %p"), breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"))+
                scale_colour_manual(values = c('#a6cee3','#1f78b4','#b2df8a','#33a02c','#fb9a99','#e31a1c','#fdbf6f','#ff7f00','#cab2d6','#6a3d9a','#ffff99','#b15928'))+

                ggtitle("Boarding the Bus Ridership November 2016") +
                labs(x="Time",y="Count")+
                theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=32, hjust=0.5)) +
                theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22))+
                theme_fivethirtyeight()
```

Comment: It's... unusual for ggplot to misplot the data. Are you sure the 2pm data is showing up in the wrong place? Or are you sure the problem is only 2pm? Your graph shows April starting above 10 at 8am, but the data has April with value 8 at 8am. My guess is the transformation is the issue, not `ggplot`. Are you sure your `time_` column is correct?

Comment: @Gregor, yeah, wow,  all the data is coming out wrong. I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe share the `dput(line_hour)` and that way we'll at least be starting from the same (copy/pasteable) place.

Comment: The way you defined `time_` didn't work for me because it wasn't considering AM/PM so the times didn't match the original times. I ended up switching to `as.POSIXct(paste(dat_on$time), origin = "7:00 AM", format = "%I:%M %p", tz = "UTC")` and the plot looks different/fine.

Comment: @aosmith that fixed both problems.  I would gladly take that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you were defining your times in `as.POSIXct` only took the hours, so the information on AM/PM got removed.

```
head(dat_on[,c(1, 4)], n = 10)
       time               time_
1   8:00 AM 2016-06-09 08:00:00
2   9:00 AM 2016-06-09 09:00:00
3  10:00 AM 2016-06-09 10:00:00
4  11:00 AM 2016-06-09 11:00:00
5  12:00 PM 2016-06-09 12:00:00
6   1:00 PM 2016-06-09 01:00:00
7   2:00 PM 2016-06-09 02:00:00
8   3:00 PM 2016-06-09 03:00:00
9   4:00 PM 2016-06-09 04:00:00
10  5:00 PM 2016-06-09 05:00:00
```

If you switch the `format` argument to give R info on how the `time` column is formatted the results look better and the resulting graph appears to make sense.

```
dat_on$time_ <- as.POSIXct(paste(dat_on$time), 
                       origin = "7:00 AM", format = "%I:%M %p", tz = "UTC")

head(dat_on[,c(1, 4)], n = 10)

       time               time_
1   8:00 AM 2016-06-09 08:00:00
2   9:00 AM 2016-06-09 09:00:00
3  10:00 AM 2016-06-09 10:00:00
4  11:00 AM 2016-06-09 11:00:00
5  12:00 PM 2016-06-09 12:00:00
6   1:00 PM 2016-06-09 13:00:00
7   2:00 PM 2016-06-09 14:00:00
8   3:00 PM 2016-06-09 15:00:00
9   4:00 PM 2016-06-09 16:00:00
10  5:00 PM 2016-06-09 17:00:00
```

Notice I used `tz = "UTC"` instead of having R use my local time zone.  This is the default time zone in `scale_x_datetime` and if I forget to do this all my times get offset in my plot.  An alternative would be to set the time zone in `date_format` in `scale_x_datetime`, e.g., `date_format("%I:%M %p", tz = "America/Los_Angeles")`.